# What is the difference between !! and nothing?

Tags: java, c++, c

Sometimes, I saw the following code:

```
if ( !!on_debugging )
```

which is the same as

```
if ( on_debugging )
```

I don't understand why these two !s are used. Is there any kind of difference?

Comment: The only thing coming to my mind is that operator ! may be overloaded.

Comment: The in this case, it is not.

Comment: If it's a non-bool, it will be 0 or 1, but that's pointless here.

Comment: If it is (say) an integer, the first `!` will convert anything positive to zero, and the second will convert the zero to one. This can be useful in some situations. Here, however, there is no difference semantically between the two.

Comment: Choose a language. If `on_debugging` is an integer, then it may work in `C/C++` but not `Java`.

Comment: -1 because .. please choose *one* language. The validity of such differs across languages (and declared types) and results may have language-specific implications.

Comment: @Spook : Or someone with a comic book sensibility to truth value assertion...

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is only a duplicate in case of C++. In C, boolean operators do not yield a bool as result.

Comment: Ultra basic obfuscation?

Answer (score 7):

`!!a` is almost equivalent to `a`. It converts it to a boolean value.

Usually this does not make a difference, but sometimes it does.

```
#include <iostream>

int a(int x) {
    return 1;
}

int a(bool x) {
    return 2;
}


int main() {
    std::cout << a(0) << std::endl;   //prints 1
    std::cout << a(!!0) << std::endl; //prints 2

    std::cout << -1 << std::endl;   //prints -1
    std::cout << !!-1 << std::endl; //prints 1

}
```

In your case, there is no difference, unless there is overloading. (But even if there is overloading, I hope there is no difference.)

(FYI, this is done even more commonly in Javascript because of its types, e.g. `false != null` but `false == !!null`. I include this comment because you tagged your question with C, C++, and Java, and Javascript shares similar syntax.)

Comment: `!` actually doesn't return a boolean value. It only returns `int` 0 or 1.

Comment: @richard.g, I beg to differ. In my example `a(!0)` returns `2`, since `!0` is of `bool` type.

Comment: The return type of `!` is different in C and C++. In C it is an `int` (of value `0` or `1`) in C++ it is a `bool`. This question is tagged for both languages.

Comment: @PaulDraper , Sorry, I didn't quite look at your example. I checked that in K&C. In c, it returns int. You are right about the c++ scenario.

Comment: Yes, in the case of C, `!` returns an `int`, whose value is `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2):

If `operator!` is not overloaded, the two statements are equivalent.

Where `!!` might be useful is if you need to change a zero / non-zero value, or a `nullptr` / non-null pointer value into a 0/1 value in an integer expression.

For a (dubious) example, the following loop counts the number of non-zero elements in a vector:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); i++)  
    count += !!v[i];
```

You will sometimes see `!!` in bit-level hacks as a result.  But in the `if` statement you show above?  Unless `operator!` is overloaded, that's not a useful operation.

Answer (score 0):

There *must* be some form of operator overloading else, it means the same.

Answer (score 0):

Take this as an [live](http://ideone.com/UqWCbV) example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int a = 5;

  printf("%d\n", a);
  printf("%d\n", !!a); // will print 1

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is a silly-warning from Visual C++.

Secondary (rare) differences include the case where you have an `operator!`, and the case where the argument is used in a non-boolean context, e.g. arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Double ! simplily means a unary NOT and another unary not. See it as `(!(!on_debugging))`

Yes, you are right, most of the time the results is the same as `on_debugging`. I think this is for preciseness or strictness to use `!!` because the `!` operator only returns `integer 0 or 1`, which corresponds to `false` and `true`. While the variable can be anything of `int` and `point` type.

Answer (score -1):

For Java `!!on_debugging` is the opposite of `!!!on_debugging`.

You can negate stuff as often as you want, thus there is no difference between `on_debugging` and `!!on_debugging`.

Also see Java Language Specification for this operator:

> The type of the operand expression of the unary ! operator must be
>   boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.
>   ([see JLS 15.15.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.6)).